# Maximum Collection

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Mark has a collection of **N** postage stamps. Each stamp belongs to some type, which are enumerated as positive integers. More valuable stamps have a higher enumerated type.

On any particular day, E-bay lists several offers, each of which is represented as an **unordered pair {A, B}**, allowing its users to exchange stamps of **type A** with an equal number of stamps of **type B**. Mark can use such an offer to put up any number of stamps of enumerated **type A** on the website and get the same number of stamps of **type B** in return, or vice-versa . Assume that any number of stamps Mark wants are always available on the site's exchange market. Each offer is open during only one day: Mark can't use it after this day, but he can use it several times during this day. If there are some offers which are active during a given day, Mark can use them in any order.

Find maximum possible value of his collection after going through (accepting or declining) all the offers. Value of Mark's collection is equal to the sum of type enumerations of all stamps in the collection.

How **dynamic programming** lead to the solution for the problem ? (Mark knows what offers will come in future)

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Programming means simplifying a problem into smaller sub-sequences of problems. Your problem is well defined as a value ordered collection of stamps of different types. So, Value(T1) < Value(T2) .. Value(Tn-1)

Finding the maximum value of the collection will be determined by the opportunities to swap pairs of types. Of course, we only want to swap pairs when it will increase the total value of the collection.

Therefore, we define a simple swap operation where we will swap if the collection contains stamps of the lower valued stamp in the swap opportunity.

If sufficient opportunities of differing types are offered, then the collection could ultimately contain all stamps at the highest value.

My suggestion is to create a collection data structure, a simple conditioned swap function and perhaps an event queue which responds to swap events.

[Dynamic Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hq7NJ.jpg)

Take a look at this diagram which shows how I would set up my data. The key is to start from the last row and work backwards computing the best deals, then moving forward and taking the best going forward.

Comment: What language are you coding?

Comment: Python(Preferable) or C++ would be fine.

Comment: int[][] events = new int[][]{  { 1, 4 }, { 2, 5 }, { 1, 3 },...}; //these events you can loop through and handle as if they were the opportunities of trading a type A for a type B

Comment: If you can add it in as answer with a bit explanation, that would be great.

Comment: I am having a problem where successive exchanging takes place, let say {4, 5}, {5, 3},{3, 1}, {1, 20} so finally 4 should be exchanged with 20

Comment: int[] myCollection = new int[]{ 1,1,2,1,0,0,0}; // this array contains my collection where the number represents the count of stamps at a particular value. The above array of events represents trades of different values. So first on is a trade opportunity of a value 1 for a value 4. I have a value 1 stamp, so I will trade it. My swap function will need to decrement the value stored in myCollection at the location of the index[1] and increment the value at index[2]

Comment: It is possible that in future there will be an offer of trading 1 with some more higher values let say, 20 so the trade of 1 to 4 should not take place.

Comment: You could add complexity/constraint in the event loop by adding the the number of trades allowed for this opportunity.

Comment: Mark can trade infinitely number of times for a given trade on a particular day .

Comment: The problem states that future offers are known. So, yes... there will be an optimal set of decisions that will result in most valued collection. This makes me want pre-process the offer sequence.

Comment: Think about critical path

Comment: How to pre-process the offer sequence ?

Comment: Think about sorting the offers

Comment: Think about putting the offers in a matrix

Comment: Yes but how the offers can be sorted as if there for a particular day there will be many offers and more profitable offers can also be on some other days so sorting on the basis of what should take place is not clear ?

Comment: columns are values ... rows are offers ... top row is the collection ... try to come up with algorithm which starts in highest value column and points back to low ... by have a understanding of the sorted offers you know that certain offers more desirable than others ... if the system dynamically creates pointers to these different offers, a path will be formed

Comment: I must leave you now, I hope I have helped. This is a hard problem ... I think some of the things we discussed will help you solve the problem ... there is no single answer for this question ... I think we have shown some ways dynamic programming can lead us to a solution.

Comment: If this is satisfactory, can you accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I would maintain a table that gives, for each type, the maximum value that you can get for a member of that type using only the last N swaps.

To compute this for N=0 just put down the value of each type without swaps.

To compute this for N=i+1 look at the ith swap and the table for N=i. The i-th swap is for two offsets in that table, which probably have different values. Because you can use the i-th swap, you can alter the table to set the lower value of the two equal to the higher value of the two.

When you have a table taking into account all the swaps you can sum up the values for the types that Mark is starting with to get the answer.

Example tables for the swaps  {4, 5}, {5, 3},{3, 1}, {1, 20}

1 2 3 4 5 .. 20

20 2 3 4 5 .. 20

20 2 20 3 4 .. 20

20 2 20 3 20 .. 20

20 2 20 20 20 .. 20

Example for swaps {1, 5} and then {1, 20}

1 2 3 4 5 .. 20

20 2 3 4 5 .. 20

20 2 3 4 20 .. 20

Note that i=1 means take account of the last swap possible, so we are working backwards as far as swaps are concerned. The final table reflects the fact that 5 can be swapped for 1 before 1 is swapped for 20. You can work out a schedule of which swaps to do when by looking at what swap is available at time i and which table entries change at this time.

Comment: Can you explain "The i-th swap is for two offsets in that table, which probably have different values" ?

Comment: I have added a worked example to my answer which I hope will explain this

Comment: Let say first up 5 can be traded with 1 and next day 1 can be traded with 20 so updating the table first up 5 remain as it is but on next step only 1 can be updated to 20. Clarify if I am wrong.

Comment: I have added another example to try and cover this. Let's hope it's really true that you can't have too many examples.

Comment: Could you explain how your algorithm addresses the issue that the swaps can be made in any order? Checking the i-th swap seems to depend on first choosing a particular order for the swaps, no? My understanding is that we are optimizing the offers for one day only - we are given all offers for that day and they are time-independent and can be repeated.

Comment: @<non-latin characters> My explanation assumes only one possible swap per day - and I now see that isn't implied by the question. However I believe there is a simple extension, in which you keep track of the best possible value for each type using only the last i days. For each day you use e.g. union find to compute a set of groups of inter-convertible types from the swaps for that day, and in each group you assign to each member the highest value reachable by any member of that group.